# .NET DataGrid Copy/Paste

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid, insert, clipboard

I have a datagrid in C# Project.
What I am trying to do is copy data from datagrid and then paste in file. Then edit content and insert back to datagrid from clipboard.

I can copy data from datagrid into clipboard but I can not insert/replace text from clipboard into datagrid.

**How can I insert data from clipboard into datagrid?**

Sample data copied from datagrid and pasted into the file:

```
>  0 base_hair00 Egyptian 0 2 2 2 2 1 _S_Hair000_Front_L _C_elf-f-hair000 0 Hair000_Bottom_S _C_elf-f-hair000 0 Hair000_Top_S _C_elf-f-hair000 0 - - 0 - - 0 - -
```

This I am trying to insert into datagrid at the end

```
>  0 base_hair02 Egyptian2 0 2 2 2 2 1 _S_Hair000_Front_L _C_elf-f-hair000 0 Hair000_Bottom_S _C_elf-f-hair000 0 Hair000_Top_S _C_elf-f-hair000 0 - - 0 - - 0 - -
```

Comment: would you be refering to the datagrid in System.Web.UI.WebControls
 or System.Windows.Forms

Comment: can you describe your question a little more? is it an issue with entering data into your datagrid in general? or just an issue with the clipboard part of it.

Comment: I am uploading demo video to show. Please wait few mins

Comment: I uploaded demo video showing what I want and problem in my app http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tgbd5qnZjr0

Comment: BTW, there is no C# `DataGrid` you meant the .NET Windows Forms `DataGrid`.

Comment: Yes I did meant .NET Windows Forms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a "Paste" function or handle the KeyDown event to listen for a Paste action like this:

```
    void datagrid_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.V && e.Control)
        {
            string data = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
            string[] cells = data.Split('\t');
            for (int i = 0; i < cells.Length; i++)
                datagrid[datagrid.CurrentRowIndex, i] = cells[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will only work if the user pastes something while **not** editing the cell. I.e. when a cell is highlighted but not in **edit** mode.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a while digging around and found the solution to your problem, look [Global Copy And Paste Option In DataGridView](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/cc563fc7-cd28-4fc0-a415-bf177868e201/), there's a link in there to code near the bottom of the posting ([second last one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vblanguage/thread/cb31a1f2-22e8-49d0-9319-0b1c105e3e96/)).